# How do I propagate a mousePressEvent() to a group of QGraphicsItems?

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qgraphicsitem

I'm writing a program that uses the Qt Graphics View framework. I have subclassed `QGraphicsItem` to a class that includes other `QGraphicsItem` (or other subclasses of it). This class is the parent of the included `QGraphicsItem`; the idea is to work with composite objects.

From the [docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#mousePressEvent) it seems to be a conflict in what I try to achieve:

- Calling `ignore()` in `mousePressEvent` will make my object unmovable. I want to move it.
- Calling `accept()` in `mousePressEvent` will prevent the event from being propagated to the child object. Some of the child objects should react to mouse events.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Have you considered sending the event on to each of an item's children by having the parent handler call QApplication::postEvent?

Comment: Ignore my last comment. Bad idea. See Styne's answer below.

Comment: I'm trying this now: Left mouse press is the start of a move action, so it is accepted in `mousePressEvent()` and handled by the object. No other object will get the event. For other input (right button, modifier keys) the event is ignored and will move to the next object.

Stynes666 is right about that there is something that doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your interpretation of the documentation is incorrect.

> Calling `ignore()` in `mousePressEvent` will make my object unmovable.

I don't believe that is true. To me it looks like calling `ignore()` is like the object saying "I have assessed this event. I have taken all actions I want to in response to this event. I have also decided it was not intended for me, so I will now pass it on to the next object underneath me". I can't find anything which suggests the ignore event will unset the `QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable` flag (which is what decides if the QGraphicsItem is movable or not).

I don't see why you couldn't make your object move **and** `ignore()` the event, but I would advise that this is not a sensible approach (in most instances: obviously you may have cause for it).

> Calling `accept()` in `mousePressEvent` will prevent the event from being propagated to the child object.

I believe this is true, but the parent can still modify its children. My understanding is calling `accept()` is like the object saying "I have assessed this event. I have taken all actions I want to in response to this event (which may include modifying my children). I have also decided that the event was intended for me, so I will not be passing the event on".

Comment: The problem with moving is caused by the lack of mouse move events: "If you call QEvent::ignore() on event, this item will lose the mouse grab, and event will propagate to any topmost item beneath. No further mouse events will be delivered to this item unless a new mouse press event is received."

Comment: So (assuming you have good reason to be responding to an event **and** saying you're ignoring it) perform your response before calling ignore.

Comment: It will make more sense to call accept() (to get the mouseMoveEvents) after notifying the children as suggested. I actually did try that by calling the childrens mousePressEvent() methods, but since they are protected members. I'm sure I can find I workaround for this, but it looks ugly. The main motivation for my question was to get a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In your parent QGraphicsItem, you might try to

```
MyObject::mousePressEvent ( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event )
{
    QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(event);
    event->ignore();
}
```

This would allow normal processing of the mouse event (i.e. make your object moveable), but then ignoring it so that it is propagated.

The logic would need to be more robust, though, because there is a high risk of side effects if a parent and child respond to the same mouse event.

Comment: I have tried this, but the problem is that after you call `ignore()` the object does not receive further mouse events. This is where the moving goes on.

Answer (score 0):

Send `QCoreApplication::postEvent(child, mouseEvent)` to child objects.